# Single Sign On with Google

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth

I've recently implemented Facebook's api to login/register an account via the user's existing facebook account.

I now want to do the same thing with Google. Is there any examples of how to do this with the Zend_Gdata stuff? I've been looking, and I can't find the proper "scope" parameter to pass to get access to the user's account information. I assume I need to use ClientLogin and oAtuh, but I'm also finding lots of (unhelpful) information about AuthSub. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: the information that Google provides is very limited regarding the information that Facebook provides, maybe thats would be your problem.

Comment: Stackoverflow already does what I am attempting to do. When you login, they give you the option of using your google account to authenticate. That's all i'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved entirely using http://gitorious.org/lightopenid

Answer (score 1):

Actually working through similar territory, only trying to use Google Apps accounts. I wanted to use Zend's OpenId, but even with the 'patches' it didn't work with Google Apps. I ended up using [Janrain's OpenId library](https://github.com/openid/php-openid), extended with Google's code for [their special discovery](http://code.google.com/p/php-openid-apps-discovery/downloads/list).

If you're just using normal Google accounts, you should be able to use the standard Janrain library - which should be able to get the profile details for you.

Comment: I looked into this library initially, but I chose LightOpenID in the end because it only require curl and it's extremely easy to use. Also, LightOpenID didn't require any "hacking" to get it to work with Google. Not sure about Google App accounts though.